# How to POST multiple Variable in JavaScript inside PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, html, post, handle

I am trying to pass multiple variable using JavaScript and PHP, but not being able to do that.

```
echo "<a href=javascript:popcontact('btsdetails.php?uid=" . $row["bs_id_site"] . "&sid=" . substr($row['bs_id'], -1) . "')>" . $row['bs_id'] . "</a>";
```

Therefore, I am trying to POST "uid" and "sid" using & sign, but it is not working. It is only accepting the "uid".

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php your passing it with $_GET

Comment: Can you please help me to find exact solution for this above problem?

Comment: urlencode(substr($row["bs_id_site"])  and urlencode(substr($row['bs_id'], -1)) then in btsdetails.php get the info with $_GET["uid"] and $_GET["sid"]

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is the answer:
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function popcontact(uid, sid){
        window.location = "btsdetails.php?uid="+uid+"&sid="+sid;
    }
    </script>

    <a href="#" onclick="popcontact(<?php echo $row["bs_id_site"]; ?>, <?php echo substr($row['bs_id'], -1); ?>)"><?php echo $row['bs_id']; ?></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [http_build_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

```
 <?php 
 $params = array("uid"=>$row["bs_id_site"], "sid"=>substr($row['bs_id'], -1)); 
 $url = "btsdetails.php?".http_build_query($params);
 ?>
 <a href="#" onclick="popcontact('<?= $url ?>')"><?= $row['bs_id'] ?></a>
```